# DLL for PowerPoint.Application

Tags: powerpoint, jacob

I am working on automation of PPT slides generation. I am using Java and my application is communicating with the Microsoft Power Point with JACOB (Java-COM bridge).

When I install just Power Point 2010 on my machine, my application doesn't work. But when I install the whole office setup, it works fine. I want to know exactly which files came with the whole Office setup to make the things work.

More precisely, I need to know which of the DLLs on my machine contains the `PowerPoint.Application` object.

Comment: By "install just PowerPoint" do you mean that you've run the Office installer, chosen a custom install and installed only PowerPoint or have you installed it by some otehr method?

Comment: Try to use object id rather then global program id.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - Yes, I ran the Office installer and chose to install PowerPoint only.

Comment: Hmm.  If I remember correctly, the bits for .Net programmability are not installed by default.  Would that be necessary for your Java-COM bridge (I'm not at all familiar with that, so this is rather a shot in the dark)